# Android - run google maps with waypoints but without specifying destination

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I'm building android application uses google maps that uses current location and list of waypoints. I want to draw polyline in the map between current location to the most far waypoint (which I don't know which one is it).

How can I ask google to give me the direction from currentLocation (I fetch it) and go through all my waypoints taking care of optimizing ?

What I'm thinking about is iterating over all waypoints and get time between current location and each waypoint and check time_duration - the biggest duration to be my last destination.

Wondering if there is any other efficient way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the criterion of the most far waypoint: driving distance, driving time or the distance as a crow fly?

Comment: @xomena driving time